# Is there any way to recursively traverse through JSON to find some property and transform it

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

In following json `name` property can be at any level in json tree hierarchy, I want to get that property anywhere I found it, first occurrence having valid value.

Note: JSON can be of any level and name property can be there at any level. Expect array as well

```
{

  "children": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "grandchildren":{
            "info":{
              "name":"Bob"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
    "name":"Bob"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not possible throguh use of Jolt